# how does Meteor.isServer works in meteor methods?

Tags: meteor

how does Meteor.isServer works in meteor methods?

Apparently instead of putting my method definitions in the /server/methods, i could put it in /both/methods and use a Meteor.isServer.
Does the code get called once in client and once in server?

I'm a little confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.isServer` is nothing more than a boolean value that is true if the code is running on the server (and false if on the client). So by wrapping your code that is in a directory that gets loaded by both the server and client ensures the code won't get executed on the client.

You would use `Meteor.isServer` in an `if` statement (this is how you would wrap your server only code).

Comment: i understand the loading part. i'm confused about the calling... how does meteor know when to call the server or when to call the client if its in the /both directory?

Comment: Meteor literally executes the javascript in the `/both` folder on both the client and server (2 times).  Since we are talking about meteor methods​ here, the code runs on the server when the app is stared (e.g. `meteor run`) and runs in the browser when the app is loaded.

Comment: so if i have a createuser in the /both why doesnt a user get created twice?

Comment: Assuming the `creatuser` isnt wrapped in a `Meteor.isServer` or `Meteor.isclient` and you are using the built in Meteor Accounts, it is probably doing a unique check and only ever creating 1 user.  The best way to verify this is to just print a message to the console. You will see a line written in your server console and the browsers client console.

Answer (score 1):

there's a difference between what code is served, and what code is run.

if you have:

```
/both/foo.js
```

... all the bytes in foo.js are part of the running server and served to the browser.

but code protected by .isServer() and .isClient() will only *run* on the appropriate platform.

to me, those are different concerns. i often don't want code served to the client, even if protected by .isServer(), because i don't want some random person seeing what our server code looks like.

Comment: i understand the loading part. i'm confused about the calling... how does meteor know when to call the server or when to call the client if its in the /both directory?